# How to get all the recent session for a user

Tags: spring-session

I'm using the spring-session project and I find it quite awesome. My requirement is to show the customer a list of his latest logins (IP address, date/time of his latest logins). I'm looking at the `SessionRepository` but I can't seem to find such a method. Is it possible to introduce such a method to return a `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` of latest sessions for a given customer? If not could anyone suggest how to tackle this problem?

Comment: You need to save them somewhere in database by using interceptors and when user successfully logged in then display the data from this table(last three).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to keep SessionRepository as simple as possible, so it will not be introduced into that API. Instead, we will likely create an extension to the interface when resolving [gh-7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/7) is resolved.

In the meantime, you can extend the existing implementation to provide additional methods that map the additional necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

for org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

example usage:

```
public static HttpSession session() {
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)    RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true == allow create
}
```